# Dynamically adding action listener to buttons

Tags: java, applet, actionlistener

i think this is wrong. i want my code to add actionlistener as soon as button is created.Is there a way to do that dynamically. look at the inner for loop i have a problem adding there

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/* <applet code = "Gridl.java" width=300 height=200>
   </applet> */

public class Gridl extends Applet 
{
     TextField t1=new TextField("    ");

     public void init()
     {
         int n = 1;
         setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));
         add(t1);
         setFont(new Font("Tahoma",Font.BOLD,24));

         for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
         {
             for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
             {
                 add(new Button(""+n));        
                 this.addActionListener(this);       // this didnt work :(
                 n++;
             }
         }  
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        String str = ae.getActionCommand();
        t1.setText(str);
    }

}
```

Comment: Read the basic Java docs on using AWT.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the specific issue here? You mention there is one but not what it is. As it stands, it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: i want to add the actionListener as soon as a button gets created in the for loop automatically i have made a comment line in my code see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have some conceptual misunderstandings reflected in your code here. It's important to consider which component you are adding the ActionListener onto.  At the moment, your code adds the ActionListener to the Gridl object extending Applet, rather than the button itself.  It won't throw an exception, because that's valid, but it won't give you the behaviour you want

To get you working, I suggest you replace

```
add(new Button(""+n));
```

with

```
Button b = new Button(""+n);
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("You clicked button "+e.getSource().toString());
    }
});

this.add(b);
```

Note that this sets up a new ActionListener for every Button object, with its behaviour determined by what you put in the actionPerformed() method.  You can have the same behaviour for all buttons, or different for each.

I would suggest that you might want to read the oracle Java Swing GUI tutorials, in particular the [one on actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).  There are code samples there too.

***EDIT:***

I have realised you might want to have your Gridl be the listener for all buttons.  In which case - you can achieve this by:

```
public class Gridl extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
     TextField t1=new TextField("    ");

     public void init()
     {
         int n = 1;
         setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));
         add(t1);
         setFont(new Font("Tahoma",Font.BOLD,24));

         for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
         {
             for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
             {
                 Button b = new Button(""+n));        
                 b.addActionListener(this);
                 this.add(b);
                 n++;
             }
         }  
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        String str = ae.getActionCommand();
        t1.setText(str);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks that was helpful but is this.add(b); really necessary i mean add(b); ain't that suffice?

Comment: Yes - `add(b);` will suffice - `this` is implicit then.  I like to keep the explicit `this.` when working with swing to avoid adding things to the wrong component etc.  Feel free to upvote / accept if it does what you want :)

Comment: so this. is for just housekeeping stuff

Comment: yeah, basically. I like to use formatting / housekeeping to keep things clear in my head.  Others don't.  YMMV

Answer (score 0):

try like this when creating button new button().add without ending that statement.

```
  new Button("").addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Execute when button is pressed
            System.out.println("You clicked the button");
        }
    });
```

Comment: how can i instantiate an abstract class in your example ?